# Must I import my category header file every time I want to use that additions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

For some reason the compiler gives me a warning that my category methods may not be there (like "foobar may not respond to doFoo"). However, the category works.

Comment: What's in the ______ supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must import your category header file. Otherwise, the compiler will give a warning for any calls to methods defined in the category. This is exactly the same as when you call a method on a class, and the method is not defined.

Because of Objective-C's dynamic nature, at runtime it will still be able to find and execute the method you call, despite the compiler warning. That is why the warning is worded "foobar **may** not respond to doFoo". At compile time the compiler cannot find a declaration of the doFoo method, therefore it may not be able to call the doFoo method correctly, however at runtime the doFoo method may be called correctly.